# Free software e-commerce site

Tags: open-source, ecommerce

I have to develop a "modest" website with support for bank card payment and payment from paypal (for buying event tickets from the website), but I've no idea about e-commerce developing, and I would like to know if there's, in the jungle of Internet, any website with any free software license, with support for such types of payment (or at least, for one of them), for exploring the source code and seen how it works.

Prefered language: PHP. Another possible alternative: Ruby.

Its behaviour is not complicated: the user selects an event he want go; then he selects the method of payment (paypal or using a credit/debit card), introduces the data (card number, security code --if any--, e-mail, and so on), the system connects to the bank or with the responsible entity for making the payment, and that's all.

There's thousand of websites with such behaviour (hotels, transport companies, etc), but I'm asking for a site with public source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PrestaShop](http://www.prestashop.com/):

- free and open source
- mostly written in PHP
- support for bank card payment and payment from [paypal](http://addons.prestashop.com/en/payments-gateways-prestashop-modules/1748-paypal.html)
- tons of other e-commerce features

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to most commom of them:

http://www.practicalecommerce.com/articles/73649-11-Open-Source-Ecommerce-Platforms

OpenCart & PrestaShop are one of the easiest to set-up.
Magento has the biggest community.
And Well, these are called Content Management Systems (CMS).

Answer (score 1):

PHP:

1. [OpenCart](https://www.opencart.com/)
2. [Prestashop](https://www.prestashop.com/en)
3. [Magento](https://magento.com/)
4. [WooCommerce](https://woocommerce.com/)

Ruby:

1. [Spree](https://spreecommerce.org/)
2. [Ror_ecommerce](https://github.com/drhenner/ror_ecommerce)
3. [Shoppe](https://github.com/tryshoppe/shoppe)